# Remove user from all AD Group Except domain users

Tags: powershell, termination

```
Get-Aduser -identity $User -Properties Memberof -filter {Memberof Name -Notlike "Domain Users" | ForEach-Object { $_.Memberof | Remove-ADGroupMember -Members $User -Confirm:$false}}
```

Hey Yall,
Im trying to remove folks from their AD Groups except for the Domain Users Group in AD (Our company is holding on to AD accounts, idk why, but they want to remove their general accesses.

When I use the above code to remove them it says: "Get-ADUser : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters."

Im not sure what way is a better way to do this.

Comment: When I look at the `MemberOf` property of an ADUser object, `Domain Users` is not included in the list. You should be able to simply remove the user from each of the groups to accomplish your aim.

Comment: Ther error is here: `-filter {Memberof Name -Notlike "Domain Users"` Just take out that part, because as @JeffZeitlin explains, this will not remove users from the default `Domain Users` group